# Программа должна создавать QR-code и сохранять его в виде картинки, но

Tags: python

```
import qrcode

value = input('Value: ')
img = qrcode.make(value)

img.save('myqrcode.png')
```

после выполнения ничего не происходит

Comment: А что должно происходить?

Comment: чтобы картинка сохранилась куда-нибудь

Comment: А вы искали где-нибудь?

Comment: пуск --- ввел название myqrcode.png --- не нашло

Comment: Искать нужно в папке, где находится этот скрипт

Comment: Огромное спасибо, чувствую себя неуклюже(

Comment: @Эникейщик этот код я увидел у ютубера и картинка сохранялась на рабочий стол, хотя код ничем не отличался, почему так?

Comment: Значит, скрипт был на рабочем столе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как оказалось код работает.

```
import qrcode

value = input('Value: ')
img = qrcode.make(value)

img.save('myqrcode.png')  # 1 вариант сохраняет картинку в папке где находится скрипт
img.save('C:\\Users\\User\\Pictures\\qrcode.png') # 2 вариант сохраняет картинку в нужное место
```